# What is the time complexity of lastIndexOf in java?

Tags: java

What is the time complexity of the `lastIndexOf` in java for using it with `String`s.
Suppose: `int t= s.lastIndexOf(c);`
where `s` is some `String` and `c` is `s.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

**For `String.lastIndexOf(int)` it's linear - `O(n)`.**

You at least need to iterate over the whole character sequence, end to start.

And that's what Java does.

Worst case: `"abbbbbbbbbb".lastIndexOf('a')`

**For `String.lastIndexOf(String)` it's `O(n*m)`** where `n` is input length and `m` is parameter length.

In this case, Java iterates end to start and wherever it finds matching last character of the needle it tries to match preceding characters on both sides as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the implementation of this method. In both code branches it contain simple iteration over string's internal array:

```
 int i = Math.min(fromIndex, value.length - 1);
 for (; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (value[i] == ch) {
             return i;
      }
 }
```

Hence complexity is just `O(n)`, i.e. linear.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as String is implemented as char array it is O(n).

```java
public int lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) {
    if (ch < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {
        // handle most cases here (ch is a BMP code point or a
        // negative value (invalid code point))
        final char[] value = this.value;
        int i = Math.min(fromIndex, value.length - 1);
        for (; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (value[i] == ch) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    } else {
        return lastIndexOfSupplementary(ch, fromIndex);
    }
}
```